# Por que o método está calculando 1 só produto?

Tags: android

Tenho um problema com um método no qual está calculando a quantidade de um único produto ao invés de calcular todos que seleciono.

Tenho certeza que o problema está na posição que passei para as variáveis quando as inicio.

Segue o método:

```
private void setEvents() {

    //Já está passando o preço do produto, mas ainda preciso calcular o preço de todos, vezes a quantidade.
    final List<Double> listaValorDoProduto = new ArrayList<Double>();
    final List<Integer> listaQuantidadeDoProduto = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final List<Double> listaValorTotalDoProduto = new ArrayList<Double>();


    /*final double[] valorDoProduto = new double[1];
    final int[] quantidadeDoProduto = new int[1];
    final double[] valorTotalDoProduto = new double[1];*/

    Button botaoFinalizarPedido = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_finalizar_pedido);

    botaoFinalizarPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double total;
            double valor = 0;
            int quantidade = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            Intent intent = new Intent(ProdutoActivity.this, ServicoDeEmailActivity.class);

            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            /*valorDoProduto[0] = app.getValorDoProduto();
            quantidadeDoProduto[0] = app.getTotal();

            total = valorDoProduto[0] * quantidadeDoProduto[0] ;*/

            listaValorDoProduto.add(app.getValorDoProduto());
            listaQuantidadeDoProduto.add(app.getTotal());

            for (Double valorDoProduto : listaValorDoProduto){
               while(x < valorDoProduto) {

                   valor = valorDoProduto;
                   x++;
               }
             }

            for (Integer quantidadeDoProduto :listaQuantidadeDoProduto){
                while(y < quantidadeDoProduto) {

                    quantidade = quantidadeDoProduto;
                    y ++;
                }
            }

            total = valor * quantidade;

            params.putDouble("ValorDoProduto", total);
            intent.putExtras(params);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

Reeditei o método, acho que assim está melhor.

Segue abaixo os métodos utilizados na classe App:

```
//Adicionando a lista de Produtos dentro de Compra (Carrinho de Compra).
    public void adicionarProduto(ItemCompra itemCompra) {

        //Percorrendo os itens da compra e passando os itens para o carrinho.
        for (ItemCompra itemCompraDoCarrinho : compra.getItens()) {
            //Se o item do carrinho for igual ao item da lista de compra...
            if (itemCompraDoCarrinho.equals(itemCompra)) {
                //Retorno a quantidade de item e somando + 1.
                itemCompraDoCarrinho.setQuantidade(itemCompraDoCarrinho.getQuantidade() + 1);
                return;
            }
        }



    //Adiciona a quantidade na lista de compras
            itemCompra.setQuantidade(1);
            compra.getItens().add(itemCompra);
        }

public double getValorDoProduto(/*ItemCompra itemCompra*/) {

        Log.i("App", "Dentro do método getValorDoProduto");
        for (ItemCompra itemCompraDoCarrinho : compra.getItens()) {

            //if (itemCompraDoCarrinho.equals(itemCompra)) {
                Log.i("App", "Obtendo o valor do item...");
                return itemCompraDoCarrinho.getProduto().getValor();

            //}
        }
        Log.i("App", "Não conseguiu pegar o valor do produto e retornou 0");
        return 0;
    }

public int getTotal() {
        //int quantidade = 0;
        for (ItemCompra itemCompraDoCarrinho : compra.getItens()) {

           //quantidade = itemCompraDoCarrinho.getQuantidade();
            return itemCompraDoCarrinho.getQuantidade();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Eric, 
Visualizando seu código você está colocando todos os valores no primeiro elemento de cada lista/array, outra coisa que não encontrei é um loop sendo feito entre os produtos, acredito que deveria haver algum código da app informando os produtos selecionados de forma que você pudesse loopar (iterar) por cada um deles fazendo a conta deles.

Faça um loop para cada elemento selecionado, passando eles e deixando que o código faça os cálculos.

Comment: Então o método que itera os produtos está na classe App mesmo. Acho que o problema é que limito o vetor a uma posição, que no caso é [0]. Tentei utilizar ArrayList, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: Não entendo porque você está colocando tudo em uma array. Outra coisa estranha é você está Multiplicando o valor do produto pelo Valor Total, Suponhamos que você tenha 1 produtos de R$ 10,00, logo o seu valorTotaldoProduto será 100, pois 10 x 10. Ao meu ver o calculo deveria ser ser valorDoProduto[0] * quantidadeDoProduto[0] ou o totalTeste[0] direto.

Comment: Reeditei e coloquei os métodos utilizados na classe App, ainda não sei onde está o erro.

Comment: Existe alguma razão para as variáveis serem `final`?

Comment: As variáveis estão como final por conta que não as declarei no escopo da classe, ai a IDE fica pedindo pra colocar o final.

Comment: Eu ja comecei não entendendo o pq `listaValorDoProduto` é um array. Você faz um foreach para recuperar o ultimo valor do array. :S. (no primeiro `for` do listener do `botaoFinalizarPedido`) a mesma coisa vale para o segundo for, vc esta recuperando apenas o ultimo valor do array. Ficou muito confuso isso.

Comment: Então Juarez, mesmo que eu não declare uma lista, o próprio Android Studio fala pra mim implementar um vetor nesses atributos.